# Encoding an integer in base64 to send through BLE

Tags: javascript, react-native, base64, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm working on this app where I'm using a Bluetooth library (https://github.com/Polidea/react-native-ble-plx) and I need to use base64 (https://github.com/eranbo/react-native-base64#readme) to pass an integer which is saved as a state to the BLE module. Is there a way to send an integer by using base64?

According to the documentation, we need the following to write -

```
device.writeCharacteristicWithResponseForService(

serviceUUID: UUID,

characteristicUUID: UUID,

valueBase64: Base64)
```

And then to write to the module:

```
device.writeCharacteristicWithResponseForService('uuidServ', 'uuidCharc', base64Data)
```

This is what I have tried so far:

```
const base64Data = base64.encode(bytes(this.state.totalSec)); 
console.log(base64Data);
```

Is there a way to get the base64 data so that I can send it to the BLE module?

Comment: what exactly is your problem? You already show code that base64 encodes something. What is the actual result and what did you expect instead?

Comment: I believe base64 only encodes strings and I want to know if theres a way to encode integers to send to BLE.

Comment: base64 also has `encodeFromByteArray`, where you can pass a byte array. Assuming `this.state.totalSec` is within bounds of UInt8, you should be able to do `base64.encodeFromByteArray([this.state.totalSec])`. Your BLE peripheral should specify what size input it expects on a given characteristic.

Comment: *I believe base64 only encodes strings* -  that's a misconception: [Base64 is a group of binary-to-text encoding schemes that represent binary data (more specifically, a sequence of 8-bit bytes) in an ASCII string format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64)